# How to put virtual hands in front of player?

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality

I want to have the VR hands always in front of the player. This works while walking forwards/backwards, once I rotate the camera they stay in the same place.
[image]

I know that I need to take the camera facing into account, but I am missing the math here. 
Here is the code for hand translation/rotation:

```
    void Update()
{
    if (UnityEngine.XR.XRDevice.isPresent)
    {
        GameObject player = GameObject.Find("PlayerGameObject");
        if (hand == WebVRControllerHand.LEFT)
        {
            transform.position = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(UnityEngine.XR.XRNode.LeftHand) + player.transform.position;
            transform.rotation = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(UnityEngine.XR.XRNode.LeftHand);
        }

        if (hand == WebVRControllerHand.RIGHT)
        {
            transform.position = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(UnityEngine.XR.XRNode.RightHand) + player.transform.position;
            transform.rotation = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(UnityEngine.XR.XRNode.RightHand);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Having no movement implemented, looking around will make the hands always appear in front of the camera. If I add this code to the camera object, it will break  so the hands never leave their original space(they still move when I rotate the controller but they stay in the same place):

```
//Script is attached to the parent of the hands
public class SimpleMovement : MonoBehaviour {
void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update 2:**
It seems like I got it partially working. At least for translation movement. I set the position only according to what comes out of the XR framework, now I add the player's position on top(previously I did this at the wrong spot).
What is missing now is rotating the camera with the sticks seemns different than rotating the camera with the headset. So the hands still do not respond to rotation movement of the sticks.

Comment: How are you handling rotating the camera right now? (I assume you're referring to something like a button/stick that rotates the player's "baseline" orientation in snapped increments, so they can turn around in game space without spinning in meatspace, not the free motion of the player's head itself?)

Comment: Are the hands put as a child of the camera? In which case, you don't have to do anything special, as long as you position the hands so that they are visible, the camera is responsible for making them follow when it rotates or translates around the world.

Comment: See my update above. Hands work fine but just adding a script for the movement will make them no longer appear in front of the camera. Even if I dont walk around, when I look 180° to the back, they do not follow

Comment: At the moment I can not get it to work. The first image still perfectly describes the problem. I guess I need to add the rotation of the camera to the hand but it does not work. hand.rotation * camera.rotation will do nothing